# how to store a drop down list value grouped with radio button to database

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

i have a laravel form with a list of radio buttons, where one button has to be grouped with the drop down.when the that particular radio button is checked, and the drop down list value can be chosen. When the form has been submitted, I want the chosen value in the drop down to be stored to the database. i dont have problem in saving the other radio buttons, which has been configured in the controller and route
I would like to know how to pass the chosen option value from the drop down to the database.
Thanks
The display is has follows
Blade view

```
<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="glass_type" id="glass_type_own" value="own">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">OWN</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="glass_type" id="glass_type_on" value="on">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">ON</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="glass_type" id="glass_type_oth" value="" >
    </label>

    <select id="glass_type_oth_opt" class="form-control"  value="" >
      <option value="">OTHER </option>
      <option value="Choose 01"> Choose 01 </option>
      <option value="choose 02"> Choose 02 </option>
      <option value="Choose 03"> Choose 03 </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
class submitted extends Controller
{
    function update(Request $req)
    {
        $sbtd = new sbtd;
        $sbtd->glass_type = $req->glass_type;
        $sbtd->save();
    }
}
```

[Blade view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuC6q.png)

Comment: give the select a name <select id="glass_type_oth_opt" class="form-control"  value="" name="glass_type_oth_opt" >   $request->glass_type_oth_opt

Comment: maybe just a typo from glass_type to glass_type_oth_opt the selected option would be passed as the value in glass_type_oth_opt

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks.! :) Now the drop down. Works fine. But the other radio button not updating..**ON** or **OWN**, the controller '$sbtd->glass_type = $req->glass_type;
      $sbtd->glass_type = $req->glass_type_oth_opt; '

Comment: @ChrisRichardson, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="glass_type" id="glass_type_own" value="own">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">OWN</label>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
      <div class="form-check">
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="glass_type" id="glass_type_on" value="on">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">ON</label>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
       <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="glass_type" id="glass_type_oth" value="" >
             </label>

              <select id="glass_type_oth_opt" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">OTHER </option>
                    <option value="Choose 01"> Choose 01 </option>
                    <option value="choose 02"> Choose 02 </option>
                    <option value="Choose 03"> Choose 03 </option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#glass_type_oth_opt").on("change", function () {

            const InputValue =  this.value;
            const input = document.getElementById('glass_type_oth');
            input.value = InputValue;
            input.checked = true;

            console.log(InputValue);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: could you able to look on this too ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/63458168/13786688)